# TexMaker configure: Cannot find control file 'reference.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?

Tags: bibtex, biber, texmaker, achemso

I try to use achemso `\documentclass[journal=ancham,manuscript=article]{achemso}` for writing paper in TexMaker but the references are all undefined.  When I run `PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX, BibTeX`, I got (my paper and reference files have the same name)

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.12 INFO - Logfile is 'paper_achemsoformat.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'paper_achemsoformat.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

I guess that something is conflict from my TexMaker setting. Because I wrote my previous paper with Biblatex and probably this time I should change the setting. Is my Bib(la)tex box in the configure is wrong? Now it is `"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" %`

[image]

I also tested `biber %.bcf` but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run BibTeX on your document, not Biber.

---

The `achemso` class brings its own set of `.bst` styles and the bibliography is supposed to be generated with those BibTeX styles. This means that `achemso` does not use `biblatex` by default (and probably should not be used with `biblatex`).

The log file and the editor settings both show that you are running Biber on your document. Biber can only be used with `biblatex`. Since `achemso` is using classical BibTeX you need to make sure to run BibTeX instead of Biber.

Essentially you need to follow [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) in reverse: Make sure that your *Bib(la)tex* command reads `bibtex %` or `bibtex %.aux`.